# How to redirect with <a> to a specific page and a specific part of the page in the same time

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

i'm new in making website and I wanted to know how i can go to another page and a specific part of this page simultaneously.

i.e: I'm in page B, and I want to go to page A at the third part with an hyperlink *(anchored with #three in html and css)* how do i have to write this please ?
I tried

```
<a href="page_a.html#a>PAGE A</a>
```

and

```
<a href="page_a.html" href="#a">PAGE A</a>
```

But it only take me to the page A and I have to click again on the hyperlink while I'm on the page A to go to the third part.

Comment: You must have element with `id="a"` on page A.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in this format.

```
<a href='yourpagelink#sectionid'>Link</a>
```

1. If your 2nd site is in same domain.

   a href="/learn-html/html-links.html#html_links"
2. If your 2nd site is in a different website.

   a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page#wikipedia"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Praveen Kumar, the first solution worked, have a good day

Comment: Please Do not write this stuff in answers and not even in comment section on Stack overflow. This community is all about questioning and answering the technical things